# How to insert two headers on the same page through word automation? - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, word-automation

I am trying to insert a header that includes a logo and a text field onto the FIRST PAGE of my word document through word automation using vb.net.

So far I have gotten the logo to show up on the right side, but I cannot seem to get the text to display on the left side of the header of the first page. Instead it will display on the second page.

Below is my code:

```
'Insert header notes.
    oDoc.Sections(1).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    With oDoc.Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .Font.Bold = False
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
        .Text = "The Shareholder Communication Strategists"
        .Font.Size = 10
    End With

    oDoc.Sections(1).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    With oDoc.Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range
        .InlineShapes.AddPicture("S:\Databases\^Tyler & Rich Database\GUI\Alliance_logo.png")
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 24
    End With
```

Any suggestions on how I can put a logo and a text on the same header of the first page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `With`-statement defines the headers of the pages starting at page 2 (because of `wdHeaderFooterPrimary`) and the second `With`-statement defines the header of the first page (because of `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage`).

If you move the content of the first `With`-statement to the second one, everything should display on the first page.

Microsoft’s reference of [WdHeaderFooterIndex Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdheaderfooterindex%28v=office.14%29.aspx) says:

> **wdHeaderFooterPrimary**  Returns the header or footer on all pages other than the first page of a document or section.

I don't know how it will display. This article might give you some usefull hints on how to [Insert Images at Specific Locations in Word Document](http://stephenchy520.blog.com/2012/02/23/cvb-net-insert-images-at-specific-locations-in-word-document/).

---

Also, there is no point in calling `oDoc.Sections(1).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True` twice.

Comment: Would you know how to format it now? Because now the text is showing on the left side. Instead its showing on the right side along with the logo

Comment: You can try to first insert the logo and then the text. But see also the link I inserted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert multiple headers or footers left, center or right, use `wdAlignParagraphLeft` and switch between positions with tabs.

```
With oDoc.Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range         
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Size = 10
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft     
    .Text = "Left" & vbTab & "Center" & vbTab & "Right"
End With
```